# Byte codes for pixel maps for Ascii characters?

Tags: graphics, text, drawing

Anyone who ever had to draw text in a graphics application for pre-windows operating systems (i.e. Dos) will know what I'm asking for.

Each ASCII character can be represented by an 8x8 pixel matrix. Each matrix can be represented by an 8 byte code (each byte used as a bit mask for each line of the matrix, 1 bit representing a white pixel, each 0 a black pixel).

Does anyone know where I can find the byte codes for the basic ASCII characters?

Thanks,
BW

Comment: IBM DOS and MS-DOS used a charset in the BIOS where each character was 8x16 pixels, not 8x8

Comment: @mads: this I wasn't aware of, thanks. I had 8x8 inmind because I drew my own 8x8 characters for a project back in *gulp* 1991

Comment: Here's a useful Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Comment: Google finds https://github.com/dhepper/font8x8

Comment: @Pi: Add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self answering because user [P i](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435129/p-i) hasn't (they posted it in a comment on the question).

This github repo is exactly what I was looking for

[dhepper/font8x8](https://github.com/dhepper/font8x8)

From the read me . . .

---

## 8x8 monochrome bitmap font for rendering

A collection of header files containing a 8x8 bitmap font.

font8x8.h contains all available characters
font8x8_basic.h contains unicode points U+0000 - U+007F
font8x8_latin.h contains unicode points U+0000 - U+00FF

Author: Daniel Hepper daniel@hepper.net
License: Public Domain

## Encoding

Every character in the font is encoded row-wise in 8 bytes.

The least significant bit of each byte corresponds to the first pixel in a
row.

The character 'A' (0x41 / 65) is encoded as
{ 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00}

```
0x0C => 0000 1100 => ..XX....
0X1E => 0001 1110 => .XXXX...
0x33 => 0011 0011 => XX..XX..
0x33 => 0011 0011 => XX..XX..
0x3F => 0011 1111 => xxxxxx..
0x33 => 0011 0011 => XX..XX..
0x33 => 0011 0011 => XX..XX..
0x00 => 0000 0000 => ........
```

To access the nth pixel in a row, right-shift by n.

```
                     . . X X . . . .
                     | | | | | | | |
(0x0C >> 0) & 1 == 0-+ | | | | | | |
(0x0C >> 1) & 1 == 0---+ | | | | | |
(0x0C >> 2) & 1 == 1-----+ | | | | |
(0x0C >> 3) & 1 == 1-------+ | | | |
(0x0C >> 4) & 1 == 0---------+ | | |
(0x0C >> 5) & 1 == 0-----------+ | |
(0x0C >> 6) & 1 == 0-------------+ |
(0x0C >> 7) & 1 == 0---------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Would [this](http://www.piclist.com/tecHREF/datafile/charset/extractor/charset_extractor.htm) do?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There are some good ones [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/fonts/); maybe not 8x8, but still easy parse

[image: tektite]

[image: fixed]

Answer (score 2):

5 x 7 [typeface](https://www.vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vector/8-bit-font-vector-5378823) would cost less space than 8 x 8.

Do you need any characters that are missing from this?

[image: ascii charset]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Bitmap?]http://cone3d.gamedev.net/cone3d/gfxsdl/tut4-2.gif

you could parse/process this bitmap and get the byte matrixes (matrices?) from this

Comment: <humor> I could do that . . . I could also do my own dentristy with piece of string, some razor blades and a pliers . . . but strangely I dont that</humor> :)

Comment: Yes Yes Yes! A million upvotes, but I may cast but one.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the font.  Search Google for 8x8 pixel fonts and you'll find a lot of different ones.

Converting from an image to a byte code table is trivial.  Loop through each image 8x8 block at at time, reading the pixels and setting the bytes.

Comment: Do that, post the byte codes and the correct answer goes to you. I don't have a fortune of time to spend on this. Thanks.